# Android NDK throwing signal sigsegv: invalid address in debug mode

Tags: android, android-ndk

I implemented the android NDK recently to hide my app keys and secrets. Since I did that whenever I run my app in debug mode in android studio, my breakpoints get interrupted with sigsegv (signal sigsegv: invalid address (fault address: 0x8)). This occurs when any of my processes access the NDK at all. I'm baffled as to what's happening as I am very new with the NDK. My C code is extremely simple, and looks something like:

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_my_company_co_utilities_UtilFuncs_getSecretOne(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
    return (*env)->  NewStringUTF(env, "my_secret_1");
}
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_my_company_co_utilities_UtilFuncs_getSecretTwo(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
    return (*env)->  NewStringUTF(env, "my_secret_2");
}
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
JJava_com_my_company_co_utilities_UtilFuncs_getKeyOne(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
    return (*env)->  NewStringUTF(env, "my_key_1");
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_my_company_co_utilities_UtilFuncs_getKeyTwo(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "my_key_2");
}
```

and I access it in my static UtilFuncs class like:

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("keys");
    }

    public static native String getSecretOne();

    public static String getSecret() {
            return getSecretOne();

    }
```

It works perfectly when I run the app normally, but it has made debug unusable entirely because of these sigsegv: invalid address errors coming up when I'm trying to read watch variables. Anyone encounter this before or have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Update: The error is not thrown on phones updated to Android 9, so my problem is resolved, but I still have no idea what was causing it in the first place. Would still be interested in any theories on the original cause.

Comment: This may not have anything at all to do with your crashes, but all of your C function signatures are incorrect: since you've declared them `static` in your Java code, they actually recieve a `jclass` as their second argument, not a `jobject`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it, but am unfortunately still getting the error in debug mode. It's really confusing me because the methods are clearly working, but any time one is called in debug it throws that up and interrupts whatever I was looking at in debug.

Comment: I've run into this one before. I fixed it somehow by invalidating caches in Android Studio and making sure all the Android SDK tools were up to date. I've also avoided it by attaching the debugger right before I perform an action that triggers a breakpoint.

Comment: Good advice, but unfortunately did not fix my issue? Can you think of anything else you did to fix it?

Comment: You can use **ndk-stack** to find out exactly which variable is causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: It's not actually crashing, just interrupting debug. and nothing is coming up in Logcat, so not sure how ndk-stack could give me a line number.

Comment: additional info. It still happens even if I never call the NDK. I have to completely remove my jni file to get it to stop.

Comment: Are you launching the *'hybrid debugger'* in Android Studio?

Comment: Don't think so. Just pressing the Debug app button button at the top. Would it launch by default?

Answer (score 13):

I discovered this thread when I experience the same: a SIGSEGV fault when running my app in the Android Studio (v3.2.1) debugger after adding NDK code. Running it without the debugger executes normally.

I have not found a solution, however I found a further clue.

After the debugger traps the SIGSEGV fault, open the breakpoints dialog.
[image]

This shows an active breakpoint at 'libart.so: art_sigsegv_fault':

[image]

There appears to be some history of sigsegv faults in libart. I did not find any resolution. However, disabling this breakpoint did allow me to continue to debug my application (a work-around).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up I appreciate it. Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I still get the SIGSEGV with that breakpoint off. I even still get it after I mute breakpoints, which doesn't make any sense. Let me know if you find a solution to your problem, in the off chance it can help me.

Comment: item 'Symbolic Breakpoints' re-appears every time I start debugging and even if I uncheck it - the errors still appear with annoying breakpoints in native code which I need to skip (over 30 times) and then the process continues.

Answer (score 3):

If you sure your C code always work fine, maybe you want to ignore error like this and debug in java.
Change "Debug Configuration"-"Debug Type" from any to "Java Only"

[guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrunc.png)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else experiences this more recently (Oct 2020 Android Studio 4.0.1 NDK 19.2.5345600):

I get the same crash under similar circumstances but only when I pass a parameter into the native method such as a jstring and only on an x86 emulator.

For example, the following code on an x86 API 30 emulator crashes as soon as it hits a breakpoint but otherwise runs fine:

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_some_package_SomeClass_someMethod(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */,
        jstring foo) {
    
    // anything ...
}
```

I can however debug this code with breakpoints no problem on an x86_64 emulator or on a physical device. So the solution is to use an x86_64 AVD or always debug on device.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small list of things to check I created through past JNI crashes I had to solve.

- You are using C native code right? Not C++? Check that everything is coherent. The file extension should be .c, and check declaration files if you have some. The "JNI tips" of [Android NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni) has a small section about it (section JavaVM and JNIEnv).
- Are you sure about the way you use `NewStringUTF`, using a string as argument this way ? Check the section "UTF-8 and UTF-16 strings" of the same [Android NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni).
- In your case the fault address is a low value. Check the "Low-address null pointer dereference" section of the chapter "Diagnosing Native Crashes" of the [Android documentation on native crash](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash).
- Did you try to put all in C++ ? I am using similar functions, if you wish to try :

myNativeLib.cpp

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring
JNICALL Java_com_my_company_co_utilities_UtilFuncs_getSecretOne(
    JNIEnv *env
    ,jobject /* this */
    )
{
    unsigned char my_secret_1[] = {0x1a, 0xb2, 0xb7, 0x39, 0x00, 0x20, 0xb1, 0x0a, 0x33}; 
    return env->NewStringUTF(my_secret_1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: To change it to C++ do I need to do anything outside the .c file other than change it's extension to .cpp on the file and where it's mentioned in the Android.mk file? Anything need to change in gradle?

Comment: Still happens in c++. I did have to change unsigned char to const char due to a type mismatch. Also is there a good way to convert a string into a single character hex array like that?

Comment: Well, it didn't fix it, but it is a good answer, and no one else answered. So I'm awarding the bounty. Please let me know if you think of anything else.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I usually just use an online converter string to hex. I don’t have access to my tools right now but will dig a bit the subject next week and see if I can find a way. JNI SIGSGEV can be a nightmare !

Answer (score 0):

**It's not a solution!**

I think that you should stick with @NoonanRosenblum asnwer and try to find the real cause of it in your NDK and fix it.

But if you don't have time for that you can just comment out a call for CMake in your module gradle build file:

```
buildTypes {
...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}


    buildTypes {
    ...
//        externalNativeBuild {
//            cmake {
//                path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
//            }
    }
    }
```

Don't forget that if you call a native method it will crash, so use it only if you want to debug step-by-step and you don't want to skip that annoying native crash breakpoints.